# message box when duplicates found

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I am trying to ask the macro to find duplicate entries in column C and then create a message box saying 'duplicate value found, please double check', here's my code below:

```
Sub findduplicates()

    Range("C3").Select

    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

        vtnaddress = ActiveCell.Address
        vtn = ActiveCell.Value

        Range("C3").Select

        Do Until ActiveCell.Address = vtnaddress
            If ActiveCell.Value = vtn Then
                MsgBox "Duplicate VTN found, please check again"
            Else
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
        Loop

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

my problem is that the message box keeps popping up (i have to kill excel to get rid of the msgbox), even though there is only 1 duplicate value found, is it because it's inside the loop? I just want the msgbox to disappear once the macro has found all the duplicates...

thanks

Answer (score 2):

this will prompt a message for every duplicate found in column "C" of the active sheet

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindDuplicates()
    Dim cell As Range

    With Intersect(ActiveSheet.Columns("C"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        For Each cell In .Cells
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Resize(cell.Row - .Rows(1).Row + 1), cell.value) > 1 Then MsgBox "Duplicate '" & cell.value & "'  in " & cell.Address
        Next cell
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when it finds a duplicate, you don't offset the active cell. Your do until loops keeps therefor checking the same cell over and over again. Assuming you only need to know if there's duplicates, you can fix it by adding an 'exit do' line as shown below:

```
Sub findduplicates()

    Range("C3").Select

    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

        vtnaddress = ActiveCell.Address
        vtn = ActiveCell.Value

        Range("C3").Select

        Do Until ActiveCell.Address = vtnaddress
            If ActiveCell.Value = vtn Then
                MsgBox "Duplicate VTN found, please check again"
                Exit Do
            Else
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
        Loop

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

That said, you may want to also have the MsgBox display WHERE the duplicate is found...

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag to determine whether any duplicate value exists or not. If duplicate value is found then you'll have to exit the first Do While loop also.

```
Sub findduplicates()

    Dim flagDuplicate As Boolean
    Range("C3").Select

    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        If flagDuplicate Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        vtnaddress = ActiveCell.Address
        vtn = ActiveCell.Value

        Range("C3").Select

        Do Until ActiveCell.Address = vtnaddress
            If ActiveCell.Value = vtn Then
                MsgBox "Duplicate VTN found, please check again"
                foundDuplicate = True
                Exit Do
            Else
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
        Loop

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
End Sub
```